# JQuery :not() selector combined with Attribute Contains selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So I have a large form and I need to select all elements that have a specific identifier in their id value.

```
$("[id*=some-value]")
```

This works wonderfully! Now I need to filter out of these results any elements that have another key identifier in their id values

```
$("[id*=some-value]:not([id*=some-other-value])")
```

which obviously is not working for me.

Currently the only element I am filtering is a checkbox so I can just use

```
$("[id*=add-contact-form]:not(:checkbox)")
```

however I would still like to know how to combine the two selector methods.

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/h86Ez/ Make sure you are using the correct values.

Comment: Yes I suspect the browser cached some code and I was not seeing that this was in fact working... my bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you already have seems to be working fine for me?

I suggest taking a look at your code and seeing if there is some underlying issue preventing that jQuery selector from working.

[Take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/BvKqS/)

Comment: Thats so weird. I've been playing with it for 15-20 minutes and that was not working for me.. now it appears it is.. sorry for the waste of time everyone!

Answer (score 11):

First of all, if your id contains "some-value" literally, then it'll automatically exclude "some-other-value".

For it to be able to pick up the other elements, the `id` has to match upto a point: "some-other-value" -> "**some-value**-other" (see how the first 2 portions match)

You can try this:

```
$("[id*=add-contact-form]").not(":checkbox");
```

or

```
$("[id*=some-value]").not("[id*=some-value-other]");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/CrD4R/)**

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Simple, less code, and attractive.

`$('*[id=some_id] option[value!=]')`

It will select all the options which have value attribute set to something and ignore with empty ones.